# String with backlash- java

Tags: java, string, escaping, backslash

I have a string as below:

```
String str="cn=sxscapp3\20,ou=Division,o=abc";
```

Now I would like to get substring of the string.

```
String newstr=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","));

Expected result : cn=sxscapp3\20

Actual result: cn=sxscapp3\
```

Any Advice on the above scenario would be helpful.

Comment: The code you've provided doesn't have a string containing a backslash. Instead, you've shown a string literal containing an octal escape sequence for U+0010. My guess is that this isn't what your *actual* code has. Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Hi @JonSkeet My program reads a ldap tree and retrieves its contexts. As shown in the example. i need to get the cn value from the whole string.When the string has a backslash, i am unable to handle the trailing characters behind the backslash.

Comment: So show that in a [mcve]. At the moment, you have code that contains U+0010 but no backslash. It's not clear whether that's *actually* in the string you're using. You should be able to demonstrate the problem without any LDAP being involved, so long as you've done appropriate diagnostic work to find out what string you're *actually* getting from LDAP.

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape the `\20` character by replacing with `\\\\20`, before actually doing the `substring`, for which you can refer the below code:

```
String str="cn=sxscapp3\20,ou=Division,o=abc";
str = str.replaceAll("\20", "\\\\20");
String newstr=str.substring(0,str.indexOf(","));
System.out.println(newstr);
```

**Output: cn=sxscapp3\20**

Comment: Hi , as i mentioned in my comments, the string value is retrieved dynamically by the program. I will have to handle the \XX value dynamically .Any suggestion would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by \XX, it is not always \20 is it ?

Comment: do you know the set of characters (array) at least to escape ? Otherwise, how to know what to escape ?

Comment: The string value retrived by the program may have a backslash. eg:cn=sxscapp3\20,ou=Division,o=abc . Another example woud be cn=sxscap3\30,ou=Division,o=abc. I need to escape the backslash and following characters until the comma.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Ascii Table...

if you print something like: **\60**

```
System.out.println("\60");
```

is the same as printing the 0 since 0 is mapped to 60(in octal base)

you need to scape the slashes first

doing `str = str.replaceAll("\20", "\\\\20");`